# What order do I apply Update Rollups?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, update

I need to apply an update rollup to Exchange 2010 SP1.  In Exchange 2003 I would do the FE's first, then the database.

Is this still the case with 2010?

Comment: How is your Exchange infrastructure set up?  Do you have an Internet-facing CAS server that proxies OWA and ActiveSync for non-Internet facing sites?  Do you have your Mailbox and CAS server roles segregated onto different boxes?

Comment: I have four Hub/CAS servers running RU3 that will be replaced with 4 dedicated Hubs,and 4 dedicated CAS servers.  All CAS servers are internet facing, though I intend to swap CAS's of RU3 with a new RU6 build.   The 4 MBX servers in the DAG will be upgraded, not replaced.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637981.aspx) (in the section called Proxying between Client Access Servers), the order that servers are updated in is as follows:

1. Client Access server
2. Hub Transport server
3. Mailbox server

There are special instructions for installing update roll-ups into DAGs according to [this Technet blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/scottschnoll/archive/2009/12/10/installing-update-rollup-1-for-exchange-2010-on-dag-members.aspx).

Comment: So if I don't use proxying, then I don't have a strict order to follow?

Comment: From the article I posted:
"For other Exchange 2010 configurations, the recommended order in which to apply the update rollup is as follows: Client Access server, Hub Transport server, and Mailbox server."  This was in the section on proxying, but it applies to other configurations as well.